# SQL Select fields with a value of 'Y' and order by date descending, then select all others and order by another field ascending

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-order-by

I am generating an SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM ToDoList 
WHERE ws_status <> 'Completed' 
AND (user_id= 'TESTUSR' OR ww_cover='TESTUSR' 
OR (ws_status = 'Orphan' AND wwt_workgroupid IN (108))) 
**ORDER BY psc_alt_code ASC**
```

And I need to list all results with wi_urgent set to 'Y' and order them by date Desc ***first and then list all other results ordered by psc_alt_code descending*** so I thought something like this would suffice:

```
ORDER BY (wi_urgent = 'Y') DESC, psc_alt_code ASC
```

I am getting `SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near '='` error when trying to run that query. Please note that I am querying an SQL View if that makes a difference?

Comment: WHERE wi_urgent = 'Y' AND ...

Comment: apologies I have updated the question. I left out a very important factor!

Comment: Do you have the option to run two separate queries for this?

Comment: No you can use a CASE expression to order by. Check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a case expression in the order by

```
SELECT * FROM ToDoList 
WHERE ws_status <> 'Completed' 
AND (user_id= 'TESTUSR' OR ww_cover='TESTUSR' 
OR (ws_status = 'Orphan' AND wwt_workgroupid IN (108))) 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN wi_urgent = 'Y' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ASC
,psc_alt_code
```

Comment: Interesting approach.  I'm having a hard time figuring out exactly what the CASE does in regards to the result set.  Are you telling SQL Server to order by the first column when wi_urgent = 'Y' and by the second column otherwise?

Comment: The case expression return's a pseudo-column, which is used for sorting. The pseudo-column data is 0 if wi_urgent = 'Y' and 1 for the rest of values. The server sort's initially on pseudo-column 0/1 value, then it sort's on psc_alt_code column

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the explanation - it's always good to learn new things. :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do `wi_urgent = 'Y'` in an ORDER BY.

Since you're looking for all results with wi_urgent, try adding it to the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT * FROM ToDoList 
WHERE ws_status <> 'Completed' 
      AND (user_id= 'TESTUSR' OR ww_cover='TESTUSR' 
           OR (ws_status = 'Orphan' AND wwt_workgroupid IN (108)))
      AND wi_urgent = 'Y'
ORDER BY wi_urgent DESC,
         psc_alt_code ASC
```

Comment: You are correct but I have updated the question as I forgot to include the fact that I want to list the results with 'Y' on top ordered by date and then all others below ordered by psc_alt_code. Apologies!

Comment: No problem :)  I'm trying to think of a way to do what you need, but I'm not a DBA and this may be beyond my ability.